# Calculate the average value of a column depending on the actual date

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've a Google spreadsheet where dates are in Column I ranging from I2:I300 and the Value is in Column C, also ranging from C2:C300. I want to calculate the average of the values which refer to the actual date subtracted by 7. So overall I want the average value of the last 7 Days, which should be `0` if no entries refer to the last 7 days. I came up with this:

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C300;I2:I300;">="&(TODAY()-7);I2:I300;"<"&DATE(TODAY()))
```

but I couldn't make it work properly.

Anyone around who has a quick and easy answer for this?

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DK7qGzMY5QbWYPye7p2BkaorCSrDfi2MAtL1GASodiY/edit?usp=sharing)

Want to get the Average "Kills" from the Matches entered the last 7 Days.

Comment: Editet my entry post with my Spreadsheet link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you can do this with sumif.

```
=sumif(I2:I300,">="&today()-7,C2:C300)/7
```

Comment: There will never be dates after today in the list as I'm writing down statistics for matches. But the formula given above won't work for me as I'm getting a parse exception error.

Comment: This is the right answer. Came from your conclusion to this: =AVERAGEIF(I2:I300;">="&today()-7;C2:C300)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
=IFFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(C2:C300;I2:I300;">=" & today()-7;I2:I300;"<" & today());"0")
```

Comment: Isn't working for me as I'm getting a parsing error.

Comment: @pnuts you are correct, I forgot that it would return an error if none were found. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Oreey try the edited answer. I put in the error check to return 0 is none were found.

Comment: @Oreey. In looking at your spreadsheet you missed a few commas when changing to semicolons. So this time I replaced them all for you.

Answer (score -1):

What error are you getting with your formula?

One- use comma between arguments instead of semicolon.

Two- With SUMIFS you need to divide the result by 7. instead use AVERAGEIFS

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C2:C300,I2:I300,">="&(TODAY()-7),I2:I300,"<"&TODAY())
```

Comment: I'm always getting a "0" as the result which is definately not right.

Comment: Ah.. my bad. Its Google spreadsheet. I should have read the question carefully before jumping on board. Will try to improve the answer